# OpenMPI: MPI.Init hanging in Java - how to debug?

Tags: java, mpi, openmpi

I've locally compiled OpenMPI with Java support according to https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=java. On my local machine with Oracle Java 8, this works fine, but on the cluster with OpenJDK 8 this approach leads to MPI Init hanging. Do you have any pointers on how to proceed from here? Dtrace? Toying with other versions of Java? I can't find any documentation on what this interface supports in terms of Java version.

```
package com.acme.hello;
import mpi.*;

public class HelloMpi {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        int me,size;
        System.out.println("attempting MPI init");
        args=MPI.Init(args);
        System.out.println("MPI init done");
    }
}

> java -version
java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)

> ~/NQSIM/java$ mpirun -version
mpirun (Open MPI) 3.1.2

> ~/NQSIM/java$ mpirun -np 2 java -classpath 
"./target/test-classes/" com.acme.hello.HelloMpi
attempting MPI init
attempting MPI init
(hangs here forever)
```

Edit: examples/hello_c shows the same behavior, so it is unrelated to Java. I guess it must be something in the transport. I had to build / install OpenMPI with user rights only. There is an existing OpenMPI on the system, but with no Java support. Any ideas on how to proceed?

Edit2: Switching to a different byte-layer, e.g. using `--mca btl vader,self`, works. The following is the output of `--mca btl_base_verbose` before the party stops:

```
[fdr4:33013] mca: base: components_register: registering framework btl components
[fdr4:33013] mca: base: components_register: found loaded component sm
[fdr4:33014] mca: base: components_register: registering framework btl components
[fdr4:33014] mca: base: components_register: found loaded component sm
[fdr4:33013] mca: base: components_register: component sm register function successful
[fdr4:33013] mca: base: components_register: found loaded component self
[fdr4:33014] mca: base: components_register: component sm register function successful
[fdr4:33013] mca: base: components_register: component self register function successful
[fdr4:33014] mca: base: components_register: found loaded component self
[fdr4:33013] mca: base: components_register: found loaded component tcp
[fdr4:33014] mca: base: components_register: component self register function successful
[fdr4:33013] mca: base: components_register: component tcp register function successful
[fdr4:33014] mca: base: components_register: found loaded component tcp
[fdr4:33013] mca: base: components_register: found loaded component vader
[fdr4:33013] mca: base: components_register: component vader register function successful
[fdr4:33013] mca: base: components_register: found loaded component openib
[fdr4:33014] mca: base: components_register: component tcp register function successful
[fdr4:33014] mca: base: components_register: found loaded component vader
[fdr4:33014] mca: base: components_register: component vader register function successful
[fdr4:33014] mca: base: components_register: found loaded component openib
[fdr4:33013] mca: base: components_register: component openib register function successful
[fdr4:33013] mca: base: components_open: opening btl components
[fdr4:33013] mca: base: components_open: found loaded component sm
[fdr4:33013] mca: base: components_open: component sm open function successful
[fdr4:33013] mca: base: components_open: found loaded component self
[fdr4:33013] mca: base: components_open: component self open function successful
[fdr4:33013] mca: base: components_open: found loaded component tcp
[fdr4:33013] mca: base: components_open: component tcp open function successful
[fdr4:33013] mca: base: components_open: found loaded component vader
[fdr4:33013] mca: base: components_open: component vader open function successful
[fdr4:33013] mca: base: components_open: found loaded component openib
[fdr4:33013] mca: base: components_open: component openib open function successful
[fdr4:33013] select: initializing btl component sm
[fdr4:33014] mca: base: components_register: component openib register function successful
[fdr4:33014] mca: base: components_open: opening btl components
[fdr4:33014] mca: base: components_open: found loaded component sm
[fdr4:33014] mca: base: components_open: component sm open function successful
[fdr4:33014] mca: base: components_open: found loaded component self
[fdr4:33014] mca: base: components_open: component self open function successful
[fdr4:33014] mca: base: components_open: found loaded component tcp
[fdr4:33014] mca: base: components_open: component tcp open function successful
[fdr4:33014] mca: base: components_open: found loaded component vader
[fdr4:33014] mca: base: components_open: component vader open function successful
[fdr4:33014] mca: base: components_open: found loaded component openib
[fdr4:33014] mca: base: components_open: component openib open function successful
[fdr4:33014] select: initializing btl component sm
[fdr4:33014] select: init of component sm returned success
[fdr4:33014] select: initializing btl component self
[fdr4:33014] select: init of component self returned success
[fdr4:33014] select: initializing btl component tcp
[fdr4:33013] select: init of component sm returned success
[fdr4:33013] select: initializing btl component self
[fdr4:33013] select: init of component self returned success
[fdr4:33013] select: initializing btl component tcp
[fdr4:33014] select: init of component tcp returned success
[fdr4:33014] select: initializing btl component vader
[fdr4:33013] select: init of component tcp returned success
[fdr4:33013] select: initializing btl component vader
[fdr4:33014] select: init of component vader returned success
[fdr4:33014] select: initializing btl component openib
[fdr4:33013] select: init of component vader returned success
[fdr4:33013] select: initializing btl component openib
[fdr4:33014] Checking distance from this process to device=mlx4_0
[fdr4:33013] Checking distance from this process to device=mlx4_0
[fdr4:33013] hwloc_distances->nbobjs=4
[fdr4:33013] hwloc_distances->latency[0]=1.000000
[fdr4:33013] hwloc_distances->latency[1]=2.000000
[fdr4:33013] hwloc_distances->latency[2]=3.000000
[fdr4:33014] hwloc_distances->nbobjs=4
[fdr4:33014] hwloc_distances->latency[0]=1.000000
[fdr4:33014] hwloc_distances->latency[1]=2.000000
[fdr4:33014] hwloc_distances->latency[2]=3.000000
[fdr4:33013] hwloc_distances->latency[3]=2.000000
[fdr4:33013] hwloc_distances->latency[4]=2.000000
[fdr4:33013] hwloc_distances->latency[5]=1.000000
[fdr4:33013] hwloc_distances->latency[6]=2.000000
[fdr4:33013] hwloc_distances->latency[7]=3.000000
[fdr4:33013] ibv_obj->logical_index=1
[fdr4:33014] hwloc_distances->latency[3]=2.000000
[fdr4:33014] hwloc_distances->latency[4]=2.000000
[fdr4:33014] hwloc_distances->latency[5]=1.000000
[fdr4:33014] hwloc_distances->latency[6]=2.000000
[fdr4:33014] hwloc_distances->latency[7]=3.000000
[fdr4:33014] ibv_obj->logical_index=1
[fdr4:33013] my_obj->logical_index=0
[fdr4:33013] Process is bound: distance to device is 2.000000
[fdr4:33014] my_obj->logical_index=0
[fdr4:33014] Process is bound: distance to device is 2.000000
[fdr4:33013] [rank=0] openib: using port mlx4_0:1
[fdr4:33013] select: init of component openib returned success
[fdr4:33014] [rank=1] openib: using port mlx4_0:1
[fdr4:33014] select: init of component openib returned success
[fdr4:33013] mca: bml: Using self btl for send to [[59315,1],0] on node fdr4
[fdr4:33014] mca: bml: Using self btl for send to [[59315,1],1] on node fdr4
[fdr4:33013] mca: bml: Using vader btl for send to [[59315,1],1] on node fdr4
[fdr4:33014] mca: bml: Using vader btl for send to [[59315,1],0] on node fdr4
```

Comment: Test local with OpenJDK would be an option.

Comment: First, you should try a C program, such as `examples/hello_c.c`

Comment: If it does not even work, try `mpirun -np 2 hostname`

Comment: Thank you both. See my edit just now - clearly, Java is the wrong place to look for the error then.

Comment: `mpirun -np 2 hostname` yields twice the same hostname. I guess shell programs are fine - does that help?

Comment: `mpirun -np 2 --mca pml ob1 --mca btl vader,self hello_c` and then `mpirun --mca pml ob1 --mca btl tcp,self hello_c`

Comment: Oh interesting, both of these come back fine. Would you mind explaining a bit? Edit: I guess either the default byte layer or P2P management layer doesn't work. Should I just keep using the ones you suggested? Does that have performance implications?

Comment: I guess `mpirun --mca pml ob1 -np 2 hello_c` will work too. That strongly suggests something is wrong with your hardware/environment/system stack. You can now `mpirun --mca pml_base_verbose 10 --mca mtl_base_verbose 10 -np 2 hello_c` to get more insight on what is going on. Since this is clearly an Open MPI issue, you are more likely to get an answer by asking directly the users@lists.open-MPI.org mailing list.

Comment: If you run on a single node, forcing the `vader` component is unlikely to hit your app performance wise.

Comment: `--mca pml ob1` was hanging too, so I figured it must be the byte layer. mtl_base_verbose didn't show anything actionable when I compared it between cluster and laptop. I'll update here in case I find out anything concret. Anyways, thanks again!

Comment: Then can you `mpirun --mca pml ob1 --mca btl_base_verbose 10 -np 2 hello_c` ?

Comment: Thanks, I've just appended the output of that in an edit. Nothing really jumping out there either.

Comment: This is pretty odd. Try `mpirun --mca btl ^sm -np 2 hello_c` and `mpirun --mca btl ^openib -np 2 hello_c`, one of these should work and point you to the faulty btl component.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't test this anymore as the issue has been resolved by support in the meantime. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

It has been resolved. In this case the problem was one of the limits imposed to users. The server was configured to use default settings, but after changing the following in `/etc/security/limits.conf` it started working with the default byte layer (since I can't test it myself directly I unfortunately don't know which ones of the two settings was the perpetrator):

```
*               -       memlock         unlimited
*               -       nofile          16384
```

Comment: Unlimited memlock is (basically) required by openib (infiniband) IIRC there was a warning/error message if this limit was too low, so there could be yet an other new issue here.

Comment: you mean there is another issue because we didn't see a warning?

Comment: Could be, I will try to investigate it.